# Black screen problem using opencv and gstreamer in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

    gst_init(&argc, &argv);
    const string gst_in = "rtspsrc location=rtsp://admin:fgfg5678@192.168.10.66:554/h264/ch1/main/av_stream latency=200 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink  drop=true";
    VideoCapture cap(gst_in, cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);

    if(!cap.isOpened())
    {
    cout << "error to open camera." << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("Received Frame",WINDOW_NORMAL);
    Mat frame ;
    // 逐帧显示
    while(cap.read(frame))
    {
    
        imshow("Received Frame", frame);
        if (waitKey(10) == 27) // Esc key to exit
            break;
    }
    cap.release();
    return 0;
}
```

opencv with `videotestsrc! decodebin !  videoconvert !  appsink` can display videos, but if you replace videotestsrc with your own video or webcam address, the screen will go black.And if you add rtph264depay in front of decodebin, the camera won't turn on

opencv with `videotestsrc! decodebin !  videoconvert !  appsink` can display videos, but if you replace videotestsrc with your own video or webcam address, the screen will go black.And if you add rtph264depay in front of decodebin, the camera won't turn on.Hope to successfully display the camera picture.